# Automatically add scrollbar to div with fixed position ancestor

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, overflow

I have a webpage with **main** content and also a popup that can appear over the **main** content. The popup will darken the background and display the popup content over everything else. I want the popup to have *maximum* dimensions so that it can have padding around the edges and not occupying the whole page. When creating my popup, I want a portion of the popup to have a scrollbar **if** the content is overflowing.

**When the page shrinks, automatically add a scrollbar to the green content in the example below and shrink the size of that green content.**

https://jsfiddle.net/maz6L8o0/122/

**HTML**

```
<body class="main">
    <div>Main content</div>
    <div class="popup-background">
        <div class="popup-foreground">
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="popup-header">header</div>
                <div class="popup-content">
                    <div class="content">
                        ghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg dfgsgdfgdsf g dfg fdsghgfds ggdf gdfsg df
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-footer">footer</div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    // Represents the main content of the web page
    background: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.popup-background {
    // Represents the background to "darken" the main content
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  
    .popup-foreground {
        // Represents the popup foreground aka, the maximum space the popup is "allowed" to occupy
        position: absolute;
        height: calc(100% - 120px);
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    
        .popup {   
            // This is the actual popup
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: grey;
            padding: 10px;
          
            .popup-header {
                background: red;
            }
            
            .popup-content {
                background: green;
        
                .content {
                  overflow-y: auto;
                }
            }
            
            .popup-footer {
                background: blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A working example online of this would be on LinkedIn when you go to edit your intro.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why, but I've gotten it to work with the following https://jsfiddle.net/maz6L8o0/201/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have added just `max-height` to `.content` div you can adjust `max-height` as per your requirements.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/gqyfv952/2/